# Where did the link to featured questions feed go?

Tags: bug, hyperlinks, rss

I am subscribed to the [featured questions feed on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/featured), which contains questions with bounties. I think I got its address from the original featured questions tab several years ago. But the new [“with bounty” tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/bounties/size) does not have a link to it.

Is there any link remaining (besides this question ☺)? Where? I believe it vanished, therefore I mark this question as [bug](/questions/tagged/bug). I want it back. If I am mistaken and it was never there, please, retag this as [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) to add the feed link to the bounties tab.